# Application that connects to multiple devices in Network

Tags: multithreading, sockets, delphi

I have an X number of electronic equipment (Weather Stations) variable on my local network, each device provides a ServerSocket connection to a specific IP and port, I have an application that connects to all such equipment, my application knows the IPs and ports of these devices as they are registered in the database, to open my application, I create a dynamically [TClientSocket (Array)] connection to each of these devices, which subsequently change a lot of information, like a conversation, ask the temperature all equipment and they answer me, or I can ask for one temperature, humidity to another, the wind speed to another etc ... through internal OPERATIONS. 
Today I do a FOR loop and all connected equipment from it know which operation with the equipment my software and then do a random conversation with every outfit, but this is slow, as it increases the number of devices increases the FOR slow. What I do is a thread to remove the FOR, I wonder if this is possible. The onConnect, OnRead, etc ... my TClientScojet events are assigned in creating TClientSocket Array, so I end up having this expecting one, then use the other and can not meet all the equipment at the same time. 
I wish I could use this Thread for all equipment and meet at the same time, but do not dominate the concept and the use, if anyone knows how I can improve this code, I am very grateful.

Today I use this class I created the extended TClientSocket:

```
type
  TTermoCenter = class(TClientSocket)
  private
    countSema: Thandle;
    access: TCriticalSection;
    ...
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Push(inObject: TPalavra; priority: Integer); virtual;
    function Pop(pResObject: pObject; timeout: Integer): Boolean;
  end;
```

Here is the constructor:

```
constructor TTermoCenter.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  access := TCriticalSection.Create;
  ...
end;
```

Here is the destructor:

```
destructor TTermoCenter.Destroy;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  ...
  access.Free;
  closeHandle(countSema);
  inherited;
end;
```

variable declaration:

```
var
  termocenters: array of TTermoCenter;
```

When creating my Form, I define the size of my Array

```
SetLength(termocenters, dm.sqlTermocenter.RecordCount);
```

And I create my connections based on what is in the database:

```
var
  SocketTmp: TTermoCenter;

  while not cds.Eof do
  begin
    SocketTmp := TTermoCenter.Create(nil);
    SocketTmp.name := 'cdsNome';
    SocketTmp.Port := 'cdsPorta';
    SocketTmp.ClientType := ctNonBlocking;
    SocketTmp.Host := 'cdsIP';
    // atribui eventos
    SocketTmp.OnRead := TCPRead;
    SocketTmp.OnConnect := TCPConnect;
    SocketTmp.OnDisconnect := TCPDisconnect;
    SocketTmp.OnError := TCPError;

    //Coloca no Array
    termocenters[I] := SocketTmp;
    try
      termocenters[I].Active := True;
      sleep(1000);
    except
      on E: Exception do
        frmMain.mmErros.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(now) + ' - ' + E.ClassName + ' CriaConexao : ' + E.Message);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  cds.Next;
end;
end;
```

This is a good summary of the code that I have today, I would like some help to implement Threads. Thank you.

Comment: Assigning character string to `TClientSocket.Port` wont compile. Are you sure your code compiles at all? It also unclear why `TCriticalSection` instance and `Sleep` call are here.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `TClientSocket` events will work just fine, provided you are creating the `TClientSocket` objects in the context of a thread that has a message loop, such as the main UI thread.

You are using non-blocking mode, so setting `Active=True` will not block your loop.  The connections will happen in the background.  When you get a `OnConnect` event, it tells you the specific `TCustomWinSocket` that is connected, so you know which particular device you can start sending commands to.  If you get an `OnError` event, it tells you if it was a connect error or not, so you can know which devices you are not able to connect to.

When `OnRead` is triggered, it tells you the specific `TCustomWinSocket` that is sending data, so you know which device is reporting information.  Since you are using non-blocking mode, the data provided by the `OnRead` event may (and usually will) be incomplete, so just buffer it off to the side somewhere (such as using the `TCustomWinSocket.Data` property to hold a pointer to a buffer that you append new data to) and only extract completed messages from the buffer, leaving incomplete messages in the buffer to be finished later.  For each complete message, you can use/update the information for that particular device as needed.

If you are having trouble using the events, then please show your actual code.  What you showed so far is not enough to diagnose any problems you are having.

Comment: Full Source Project
https://mega.co.nz/#!bAVBwTAb!fdzyS9ENPMWul3wC8GFkKATiJ7whKB7Xzgo5FUHlD6M